# Recursively expand collapsed regions in Visual Studio? (outlining)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, outlining

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, and it doesn't seem like once I have collapsed all the regions, I can expand ALL levels of a certain region with one click/command. Notepad++ has this functionality when you <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + click on a collapsed region, it recursively expands all regions within it. It's awesome.

Anyone know of a plugin or macro that has this functionality?
I'm using a custom language, aka not C++/C# btw

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I am working with VS 2017, but I think it works the same:

By default, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> expands at the current line.

But if you choose several lines (e.g., <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>drag the mouse</kbd>), then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ME</kbd> expands everything at all those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just this:

1. Click on the collapsed region name

[image]

2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>