# In Visual Studio 2017 can I recursively expand a collapsed element?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard, visual-studio-2017, keyboard-shortcuts

Often I'll use <kbd>Ctrl+M+A</kbd> to completely collapse the entire files, and then drill in from there.

However I would like to be able to be able to click to expand an element in such a way that recursively expands all children elements. Notepad++ has this ability with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click.

After searching all I could find was [this unanswered question from 5 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149718/recursively-expand-collapsed-regions-in-visual-studio-outlining) ago regarding Visual Studio 2008.